# WSO2 analytics server database is growing

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am using WSO2 API Manager along with it's analytics server. I configured MySQL as it's database.
After a year of PROD use, I found that there are couple of tables from Analytics module, which consumes most of the DB space, around 95%.

Would like to know the significance of these tables. As well the challenges if we delete those tables.

Table names are

```
+--------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Database                       | Table                                                | Size in MB |
+--------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| wso2_analytics_event_store     | anx___7lsekeca_                                      |     665.03 |
| wso2_analytics_event_store     | anx___7lmnf2xa_                                      |     638.00 |
| wso2_analytics_event_store     | anx___7lqcf_8o_                                      |     636.14 |
| wso2_analytics_event_store     | anx___7lmk3tr0_                                      |     398.13 |
| analytics_processed_data_store | anx___7lpteea4_                                      |     282.75 |
| analytics_processed_data_store | anx___7lsn7ita_                                      |     249.97 |
| wso2_analytics_event_store     | anx___7lsgqyce_                                      |     209.25 |
| wso2_analytics_event_store     | anx___7lmno15m_                                      |     207.25 |
| wso2_analytics_event_store     | anx___7lver1fy_                                      |     191.16 |
```

Comment: what's the version?

Comment: The version is 2.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable data purging for analytics tables. See below section taken from the docs.

[image]

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Purging+Analytics+Data

Comment: Ahh. Okay. That is good to know. I will check this option and get back if face any challenge.